# Issue: Violation of Permissions policy, Call Log Permission

Tags: permissions, policy, calllog

I made an app where first it reads the call logs and also requests for contacts to match the numbers to get contact images and display to the user within my application. After selecting any contact number, it opens that user's conversation to WhatsApp directly. I have also filled the declaration form. However, I received many rejection emails that call logs is not my core functionality and I should remove this feature from my mobile application.
As you can see that it is my core functionality to display the call logs and contacts to the user so that he can select to open it in WhatsApp Conversation Directly.

The permissions i declared in the manifiest file as shown below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.crymzee.saveless_new">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```

The Picture of Google Play rejection is added below

[image]

Is there any other way to get call logs or which use case matches my App functionality?

What functionalities in your app require SMS and Call Log permissions?

Default SMS handler

- Default Phone handler
- Default Assistant handler
- Transactional backup and restore for users and archive for enterprise    (time-limited/non-continuous)
- Enterprise archive, CRM, and device management
- Caller ID, spam detection, and blocking
- Connected device companion apps (for example, smartwatch or       automotive)
- Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls
- SMS-based financial transactions and related activity where access is    restricted to financial SMS transactions (for example, 5-digit messages)
- SMS based money management
- Proxy calls
- Services - Carrier
- Services - OEM
- Device Automation
- Physical safety / emergency alert apps (e.g., senior safety)
- Call-based OTP account verification
- Using SMS_CB_RECEIVED for customer communications (e.g., Smart Zone    Cast service)
- Write and Show Call History in Dialer
- In-vehicle hands-free use or projected display
- Anti-SMS Phishing

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No i did not solve it

Comment: Wow, 5 months. I have the same issue.